# How to pass route attribute but not pass the htmlattribute in ActionLink in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just want to know why don't we have an overload for Action link like below.

```
@Html.ActionLink(displayName, actionName,controllerName,routeValue)

@Html.ActionLink(@item.Resume.ResumeName, "Details","Resume", new { id=item.Id})
```

When I do something like below everything works fine

```
@Html.ActionLink(displayName, actionName,controllerName,routeValue,"")

@Html.ActionLink(@item.Resume.ResumeName, "Details","Resume", new { id=item.Id},"")
```

I checked the overload and with four parameter the only overload available is

```
@Html.ActionLink(displayName, actionName,controllerName, htmlattribute)
```

So, I am a beginner and just wondering is there any particular reason for not having an overload with routevalue 4th argument(last argument). So basically with current framework, if I need to send a routevalue its mandatory for me to set 5th parameter as well (empty string).

Comment: Oh, and the overload will get confused. Ya that makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActionLink()` methods allow you to add route values **and/or** html attributes, both of which accept `object` as its arguments.

If the signature was just

```
@Html.ActionLink(string displayName, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
```

then if you were to pass `new { id = 1 }` as an argument to the 4th parameter, there would be no way to distinguish if you wanted it to be added as a route value or a html attribute.

Note that there is no overload with `@Html.ActionLink(string displayName, string actionName, string controllerName, object htmlAttributes)` as you claim. The overload is actually

```
@Html.ActionLink(string displayName, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink(string displayName, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

and to add just route values, you typically pass `null` to the last parameter.